# Function to add empty colum in data frame when column of another df is different in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2. The df1 contains:

```
t <- c(0,2,0,0,2,0,2)

cool <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
bad <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0)
great <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1)

df1 <- data.frame(t, cool, bad, great)
```

The df2 contains one additional column

```
no <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1)

df2 <- data.frame(t, cool, bad, great, no)
```

Now I want to create a function, that adds the empty column to df1 (filled only with zero) and the name of this empty column corresponds to the column that is not in common with df2 (here it is column "no" that should be empty and added to df1). This function should work for all other columns not in common so that is automatically add an empty column to df1.
The beginning would be maybe something like

```
addcolumn <- function(df1, df2) {
 w<- which((df1) != ncol(df2)){
   }
 }
```

thank you for an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
# names of columns in df2 that are not in df1
cols <- names(df2)[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))]

# ...or
cols <- setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))

# add cols from d2 to df1
df3 <- cbind(df1, df2[ , cols, drop = FALSE])

# set cols from df1 to zero
df3[ , cols] <- 0
df3

#   t cool bad great no
# 1 0    0   1     1  0
# 2 2    1   0     1  0
# 3 0    0   1     0  0
# 4 0    0   1     0  0
# 5 2    1   0     0  0
# 6 0    0   1     0  0
# 7 2    1   0     1  0
```

**Update** following comment: a more general solution where `df2` may have a different number of rows than df1.

```
df2 <- data.frame(t = 1:8,
                  no = 1:8,
                  yes = 9:16) 

# names of columns in df2 that are not in df1
cols <- names(df2)[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))]

# create a matrix of zeros
# number of rows equals number of rows in df1
# number of columns equals number of new variables   
m <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df1), ncol = length(cols), dimnames = list(NULL, cols))

df3 <- cbind(df1, m)
df3
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you found my answer helpful! Cheers.

Comment: I have another question. It is possible to modifiy the code when     df2 <- data.frame(t, cool, bad, great, no) has different row length than df1 ? I get an error "arguments imply differing number of rows"...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. The `df2` in your comment looks the same as `df2` in your question.

Comment: If no2 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1) in df2 has eight or more values than no <-c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1) in df1, I mean the number of the rows of each element in one dataframe is different..